# Activadores en Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, trigger, google-apps-script

Se que usando Google Apps Script se puede configurar un activador, para que corra cada cierto tiempo,  pero quisiera poder configurarlo desde el código.

Hice una aplicación para mi trabajo que tiene un proceso que tiene que correr cada hora, y tengo que configurar este activador en cada usuario que le pase mi programa, por eso quisiera que se pudiera programar para incluirlo dentro del código y cuando se instale con un usuario, se configurara el activador.

Answer (score 1):

El "Script Service" de Google Apps Script cuenta con la [clase Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger) (disparador). Puedes crear un nuevo disparador usando el método [newTrigger(functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname).

Cabe mencionar que es probable que te convenga crear un complemento. La documentación sobre esto está en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/

Answer (score 1):

Como bien ha dicho Rubén con la clase Trigger deberías poder hacerlo a través de código, **pero** es posible que te dé problemas. (principalmente que a veces no se dispare)

Ahora mismo no se como está el tema pero hace un tiempo al menos era aconsejable usar los disparadores manuales ya que los disparadores por código no acaban de ir bien. (desconozco si hoy día esta parte la han arreglado/mejorado)

Disiento con Rubén ( lo siento :) ) respecto al addon dado que el proceso de publicar un addon es bastante pesado (hay bastantes filtros de calidad totalmente lógicos pero que complican demasiado el proceso) y además no tiene mucho sentido siendo un script para dentro de una empresa (entiendo que el script corre sobre el dominio de la empresa, por lo que no interesa que sea público como debería ser con el addon)

Por contra yo te recomendaría otra opción: Tener un solo disparador en un script tuyo. Puedes explicar mas o menos y sin detalles que debería hacer tu script? Necesita permisos para cada usuario? Depende de lo que tuviera que hacer tal vez te valdría la pena tener tu el disparador en tu script maestro y que procesara la información de los usuarios que se hayan registrado.

Cuando programo scripts para mi empresa (y lo hago diariamente :)) intento siempre que los usuarios sean usuarios y no propietarios del script. Así lo tienes todo centralizado, facilitas la corrección de bugs y controlas mejor los permisos.

Si das mas detalles de lo que tiene que hacer tu script refino mi respuesta un poco más.